# Change the brightness/contrast of an image in EmguCV

Tags: emgucv

I have a program that will load an image from the hard disk. The program is written using emgu cv and the image is a Bgr image. I want to allow the user to increase/decrease the brightness/contrast of the image. How can I do this? Some sample code would be appreciated (because I am still a newbie). Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on your image adjustment requirements.

You can start using some basic techniques already wrapped in emguCV such as histogram equalization and gamma correction. You can also combine them to achieve better result.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> inputImage;
inputImage._EqualizeHist();
inputImage._GammaCorrect(1.8d);
```

Comment: Just some basic adjustment. Increase/decrease the brightness and the contrast. That's all...